# Constraints comparator

Tags: constraints

Do you know a tool I could use to compare constraints (not only mathematical)? It's easier to explain with examples:

A) Simple example

```
C1: x < 0 && y * y < x
C2: x < 0 && y * y < x - 1
```

I want to know if C2 is stronger then C1, and it is. That means, (x,y) of C2 are also in C1.

B) Complicated example

```
C1: x > 0 && y > 0
C2: x > 0
```

C2 is weaker then C1 because it doesn't contain constraints on y.

I can try to write something by hand, but I don't think this is a solution. I know that the problem of solving constraints is undecidable, but I would like to know what work has been done in this direction.

Thanks,

Comment: Out of curiosity, in what situation might you need to do this?

Comment: I'm working on a project that analyzes code bases and generate some reports. For example private foo(int x) { if (x < 0) throw new RuntimeException(); } and it's called from bar() { return foo(2 * x); }. I'm trying to report that in bar() you call a method without satisfying the preconditions (x >= 0 for foo()). If bar would be { if (x < 0) x = -x; return foo(2 * x); } then everything would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to decide if a constraint C1 subsumes C2 (meaning that it is not possible to find a set of values that satisfy C1 and not satisfy C2 -> C2 is true in all scenarios in which C1 is true but maybe not the other way around)?. When C1 subsumes C2 then C2 can be removed since it does not add any semantics to the problem.

If this is the case, I´d recommend you to use a CSP solver for that. It is easier than it seems. For instance, the Eclipse CSP solver (here Eclipse does not referes to the IDE platform, the solver has the same name) can be easily called from your java program through a well-defined API so you could just sent the problem to the solver and see which constraint is weaker

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try the Eclipse CSP solver and then I'll give you "question answered" ;-).

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question! You could write a script that parses each constraint and checks the number of separate comparisons in each one although I'm not sure if that is the best way to measure them.

Comment: I think this is trivial. I can write a dummy tool for my cases, but I think somebody did this before.

Comment: The number of seperate comparisons won't get you the stronger/weaker link, will it? For example, his first example has the same number of comparisons in each case, but they aren't equally as strong.

Comment: No, because I don't have the constraints in the normal form (simplest possible). I could have something as: x < 0 && x * x > 0 && x * x * x < 0 and so on, which is actually x < 0